# Gradle and Android Studio issue when running JUnit tests using Robolectric

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

The app's build.gradle is:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp.robolectricexample2"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2'
    compile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

So, I get the following error:

> Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. >
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_31\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: Just last night I ran into a similar exception, I didn't have the correct dependency. Also, you might want to update your `build.gradle` to the newer versions. I'll update my answer, do not give up! You are close to finishing this.

Comment: Also, make sure you have the latest dependencies downloaded from the Android SDK manager.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but I seriously hesitate that I'll try it again. It tried robolectric for the first time several months ago and I wasn't able to make it work; then someone told me that it was great so I promised to try it again in the next Android app project I'd be involved in. And again, I wasn't able to make it work, so I cannot spend more time on this. I think the project needs maturity in the setup part, that's all.

Comment: Ok, I am using that exact build gradle in some of my projects. So if you ever come back, use my updated answer.

Comment: Alright, I'll write it down in my notes repository (I seriously do) and I'll give it a try in the next project, if I feel brave enough to do that ;) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Try this `build.gradle`

```
android {
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 22
        buildToolsVersion "22.0.1" // <-- was 22.0.0

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp.robolectricexample2"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1' // <-- was 22.0.0
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc2'
}
```

Now you can run **`gradlew testDebug`**.

Put your tests in **`src/test`**.

Comment: That doesn't sove the issue. Anyway I'd like to run the tests from Android Studio, not from the command line...

Comment: @Luis Tell me what is wrong. Did you fix your dependencies? Did you put your tests in src/tests?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. In my case, I found the reason is that I put my test files in the wrong directory.

My old project structure is:

```
app
|-src
|  |- main
|  |- androidTest <- I put here.
|  |- test <- The test files should be put here.
|-build
```

I moved my test files to android default unit test directory src/test/java, then the problem was solved.